# jenkins maven build: access denied to maven settings.xml

Tags: maven, jenkins

I get this error when building my maven project:

```
[FATAL] Non-readable settings C:\MAVEN 3.2.2\conf: C:\MAVEN 3.2.2\conf (access denied) @ C:\MAVEN 3.2.2\conf

    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:128)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:109)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:136)
    at hudson.maven.MavenUtil.createEmbedder(MavenUtil.java:212)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1288)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1091)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:920)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:893)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.parsePoms(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:953)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:681)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:535)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1732)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)
Caused by: hudson.maven.MavenEmbedderException: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective settings
[FATAL] Non-readable settings C:\MAVEN 3.2.2\conf: C:\MAVEN 3.2.2\conf (access denied) @ C:\MAVEN 3.2.2\conf

    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.getSettings(MavenEmbedder.java:261)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.buildMavenExecutionRequest(MavenEmbedder.java:157)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:120)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.settings.building.SettingsBuildingException: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective settings
[FATAL] Non-readable settings C:\MAVEN 3.2.2\conf: C:\MAVEN 3.2.2\conf (access denied) @ C:\MAVEN 3.2.2\conf

    at org.apache.maven.settings.building.DefaultSettingsBuilder.build(DefaultSettingsBuilder.java:116)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.getSettings(MavenEmbedder.java:259)
    ... 16 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

Is it because of the C drive? Is there an easy fix or do I have to put maven on another drive? That would be a pain in the ass...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a filesystem permission issue. Make sure that the OS user running Jenkins has read permission to C:\MAVEN 3.2.2.

**Edit**: Based on your comment it is probably not a filesystem permission issue. However I just noticed that the following message shows a directory name while it should be a file name:

```
Non-readable settings C:\MAVEN 3.2.2\conf
```

Look in your Jenkins build configuration, under the Build section, click the Advanced button and check if you have a value defined for "Settings file".

Comment: where do I configure that? I am the only user. I start jenkins over the command line, which I execute as admin.